Is Nettles the Dragonrider black or brown?
There is a lot of debate on the absence of Nettles from the show House of the Dragon, and one argument is about her ethnicity analogue vis-a-vis our own world.
Many seem convinced that she was black. However her appearance is described as a Brown skinny girl with black hair and black eyes. That could easily be Salty/ Sand Dornish which is an analogue to Hispanic/ Middle Eastern/ South Asian races in our world rather than African.
Then there is also George R. R. Martin's description of other canon Black Characters who are explicitly described as Black rather than Brown such as  Jalabhar Xo, Bellegre Otherys, Chataya, Quhuru Mu, Kojja mu, Black Balaq etc. To my knowledge GRRM has never referred to a Black character as Brown. That always made me believe that Nettles had Dornish ancestry which would be more probable given the demographics of Westeros. But she lived in a port town so Summer Islander sailors would have visited her town a lot, which could also make her black.
Is there any clear answer from GRRM on the matter? Any interview or GRRM-endorsed artwork which could settle that debate?

If the idea is something along the lines of "the writers do not want to have a lot of Black characters on the show and their not incorporating one such character from the story is the proof of it," wouldn't "the writers don't want to have many characters of color in general on the show and the absence of one such character is the proof of it" be equally plausible? I guess some people think that if they can "prove" that she looks more Asian or Middle Eastern, then that would demonstrate something, but it is not clear that it would.

Define 'black' and define 'brown'. Are you talking about her literal skin colour or her ethnicity? Many 'black' people are dark-skinned where probably just as many are fairer and can look brown. Then again, if Nettles is in fact a half-caste from one of the darker-skinned locations, she would actually probably be 'brown-looking' any way...

Also, Fire and Blood is written based on the testimonies of various people, likely the descriptions used are likely from the perspectives and biases of those people (in this case, likely Mushroom).

I believe, it ultimately doesn't matter which colour GRRM intended Nettles to be. The showrunners can (and have) changed the ethnicities and even genders of characters - either to assist with diversification or to suit their needs for the character.

There's an animated featurette called The Dance of Dragons which was released in 2016 as bonus material in the Blu-ray release with Digital Copy of Game of Thrones Season 5. That recount of the titular event features a portrayal of Nettles as a person of an ethnicity that we would recognize in real-world as African ancestry.

@Möoz I should clarify, My question is about her ethnicity (Or analogue thereof vis-a-vis our real world), not her skin colour which is clearly stated of course. And yes indeed does not matter at all to the plot. Besides, as you say THOTD is not really a close adaptation and HBO has taken a lot of liberties. Coming back to the question, we know she is a bastard, we know she is from Driftmark, we know she had brown skin. But is she of mixed summer island heritage? Rhoynar heritage? Or something else?

@Gae.S. That may be closer to an answer. Now we gotta figure out GRRM's endoresement of it. I have also discovered that There is a prequel companion book The Rise of the Dragon and it has her portrait as an African woman (I don't have the book yet but I am going to confirm if it is indeed in there)

The official art work from "The Rise of the Dragon" companion book by GRRM, Elio Garcia & Linda Antonsson depicts Nettles as a Black Woman.

Furthermore a screencap from HBO  'Complete Guide to Westeros' featurette, featured on the Game of Thrones - Season 5 Blu-ray edition also depicts her as a Black woman.

Thus it is clear that in both book canon and show canon, Nettles is of Mixed Summerislander heritage.

I'm at a loss why you've made this a community Wiki. Are you expecting others to add something to this?

@Valorum Because HBO half of the answer is actually by gae-s in the comments. Feels unchivalrous to get rep from that hence the wiki.
